# Prevent Overlapping in FacetGrid using col, row, and hue

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

I have a plot that looks fine

```
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')

sns.violinplot('day', 'total_bill', data=tips, hue='sex')
```

[image]

However, when I want to create a facet using the `FacetGrid` object,
the violins, in this example, are plotted on top of eachother.
How do I prevent tha from happening so the Male and Female are plotted next to each other?

```
facet = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col='time', row='smoker', hue='sex',
                 hue_kws={'Male':'blue', 'Female':'green'}).
facet.map(sns.violinplot, 'day', 'total_bill')
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't see the option to add plots from my computer :x

I updated all the posts with pictures

Comment: @mwaskom: thanks, seems like `sns.factorplot(x='day', y='total_bill', hue='sex', data=tips, row='smoker', col='time', kind='violin')` did the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The better solution proposed by @mwaskom is to use `factorplot`

```
sns.factorplot(x='day', y='total_bill', hue='sex', data=tips,
               row='smoker', col='time', kind='violin')
```

[image]

Comment: Multiple answers and pics. Way to go! :)

Answer (score 2):

Seems the solution is:

```
import seaborn as sns
facet = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col="time", row='smoker')
facet.map(sns.violinplot, 'day', 'total_bill', "sex")
```

[image]

passing `sex` into the `map` call seems to do what I wanted.
However what is the name of the parameter that `sex` is assigned to?
It's not `hue`.  Anyone know what is actually being passed here?

The other way is to do it barebones from the `matplotlib.pyplot` level

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

facet_fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = facet_fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 1)
ax2 = facet_fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 2)
ax3 = facet_fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 3)
ax4 = facet_fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 4)    

sns.violinplot(x='day', y='total_bill', hue='sex', ax=ax1,
               data=tips[(tips.smoker=='Yes') & (tips.time == 'Lunch')])
sns.violinplot(x='day', y='total_bill', hue='sex', ax=ax2,
               data=tips[(tips.smoker=='Yes') & (tips.time == 'Dinner')])
sns.violinplot(x='day', y='total_bill', hue='sex', ax=ax3,
               data=tips[(tips.smoker=='No') & (tips.time == 'Lunch')])
sns.violinplot(x='day', y='total_bill', hue='sex', ax=ax4,
               data=tips[(tips.smoker=='No') & (tips.time == 'Dinner')])
```

[image]

Comment: actually, I figured it out.  `map` will take positional arguments, from `sns.violinplot` the order of parameters is `x`, `y`, and then `hue`.

So `sex` is getting passed into`hue`, just doesn't work as a kwarg